# PHP exec() not running properly

Tags: php, command

When I execute the code below in command line it runs fine:

```
C:\Users\Shraddha\book ticket\ex1 scrapy crawl bookmyshow
```

However it doesn't execute in PHP using `exec()`:

```
exec("C:\Users\Shraddha\book ticket\ex1 scrapy crawl bookmyshow");
```

Comment: What does `exec` return to you?

Comment: It dosen't  return any message @ Jon Stirling

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the blank characters in the path, otherwise they are interpreted as separator between multiple arguments. Also it is much safer to use the forward slash as folder separator as it is used in unixoid systems and the internet in general:

```
exec("C:/Users/Shraddha/book\ ticket/ex1\ scrapy\ crawl\ bookmyshow");
```

If you insist on MS-Windows style separators, then you have to escape them too:

```
exec("C:\\Users\\Shraddha\\book\ ticket\\ex1\ scrapy\ crawl\ bookmyshow");
```

Also you may prefer to use `shell_exec()` here to have a well defined and initialized environment for your command to be executed in.